# Error in res.render, function not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have developed an application using express js. I am trying to fetch data from my mongo collection, below is the javascript file and on fetching the data i am passing the data to a jade file through res.render function. One point to note is that i have several functions like the one below and all are synchronous. Still my console says "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

It is showing error on res.render line.

Any help is deeply appreciated. If someone needs more info about the question, please let me know.

```js
exports.getData_app = function(req,res){

 var nine = function(callback){
                wpt_results.find({$and: [{"Environment":"app"},{"Module":"paid"},{browser_name:'Internet Explorer'}]},{},function(e,docs){
                        console.log('here is the doc fetched from the collection app');
                       // console.log(docs);
                        len = docs.length;
                        console.log('here is the length of the docs fetched in app');
                        console.log(len);
   console.log("we are in the new one app javascript file");
   console.log("here is the much awaited result"+req.params.id);
                        for(i=0;i<docs.length;i++){

                            dates_apppaid_ie.push(docs[i].Date);

                            ttfbs_apppaid_ie.push(docs[i].TTFB);

                            lt_apppaid_ie.push(docs[i].loadTime);

                            url.push(docs[i].Url);

                        }

                        for(i=0;i<len;i+=2){
                            pre_final_str_apppaid_ie.push(dates_apppaid_ie[i]+","+ttfbs_apppaid_ie[i]+","+ttfbs_apppaid_ie[i+1]+","+lt_apppaid_ie[i]+","+lt_apppaid_ie[i+1]+"\\n");
                        }
                        console.log(pre_final_str_apppaid_ie);
                        console.log(pre_final_str_app.length);
                        for(i=0;i<pre_final_str_apppaid_ie.length;i+=2){

                            final_str_apppaid_ie += pre_final_str_apppaid_ie[i].concat(pre_final_str_apppaid_ie[i+1]);
                        }

                        console.log('app ---->>>>>'+final_str_apppaid_ie);
                        res.render('index1.jade',{final_str_appreporting: final_str_appreporting,final_str_apppaid: final_str_apppaid, final_str_app: final_str_app, final_str_app_firefox:final_str_app_firefox,final_str_appreporting_firefox:final_str_appreporting_firefox,final_str_apppaid_firefox:final_str_apppaid_firefox,final_str_app_ie:final_str_app_ie,final_str_appreporting_ie:final_str_appreporting_ie,final_str_apppaid_ie:final_str_apppaid_ie});
                    });
                callback(null,nine);
            }
```

Comment: `res` is never defined in your code.

Comment: i have defined it, i have edited the screenshot. please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I was getting this error because i had defined a string with the name "res". On changing it to something else, res.render is working fine.